# GE Plugin KML Network Link Duplicate Placemark Issue

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth-plugin

I have a very simple network link being loaded into the Google Earth Plugin with a single placemark (for sake of simplicity...ultimately I will have several hundred).  I have this link refreshing on a one second interval.  The placemark displays fine on the globe.  My problem is that when the user clicks the placemark it creates a duplicate placemark that stays on the globe.  This happens if the placemark location changes between refreshes or not.  At first I thought this might be a data problem with the download.  It is not. The duplicate placemark will remain exactly at the point where the user clicks.  If the coordinates are static Google Earth treats as overlapping placemarks.  When I set the point in motion you get breadcrumbs whenever a click occurs.

Here is my KML to load the network link.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Folder>
    <name>Network Link Folder</name>
    <visibility>1</visibility>
    <open>0</open>
    <description>Network Link Example 1</description>
    <NetworkLink>
      <name>Placemark</name>
      <visibility>1</visibility>
      <open>0</open>
      <description>Test</description>
      <refreshVisibility>1</refreshVisibility>
      <flyToView>0</flyToView>
      <Link>
        <href>http://localhost:8080/link1?param=2</href>
       <refreshMode>onInterval</refreshMode>
       <refreshInterval>1</refreshInterval>
      </Link>
    </NetworkLink>
  </Folder>
</kml>
```

Here is my KML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:xal="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0">
    <Folder>
        <Placemark id="mark0">
            <name>mark0</name>
            <Style>
                <LabelStyle>
                    <scale>0.0</scale>
                </LabelStyle>
            </Style>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>30.961997255872557,-1.6772876374935848</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
</kml>
```

I toyed with my approach trying to use fetchKml instead but there are issues with that as well.  Mainly there is a caching bug discussed here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-earth-browser-plugin/M5tDZfAV4gA.

I have also tried adding a click handler in an attempt to try to swallow the click event to prevent this from happening.  That did not work out either.

Perhaps someone out there can help. Below is my Google Earth Version Info.

```
Google Earth
7.1.2.2041
Build Date
10/7/2013
Build Time
12:28:36 pm
Renderer
DirectX
Operating System
Microsoft Windows (6.0.6002.2)
Video Driver
Google Inc. (00008.00015.00010.02202)
Max Texture Size
4096x4096
available video memory
1759 MB
Server
kh.google.com
```